# Setting up a service account with write permission to BigQuery Dataset

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I can't find a way, to setup, using Google Cloud SDK (`gcloud` or `python` in this case) a service account that can write into a BigQuery Dataset.

When calling `bq insert ...` I get the following error:

```
BigQuery error in insert operation: 

Access Denied: 
Dataset DATASET_NAME: The user service_account@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com 
does not have bigquery.datasets.get permission for dataset DATASET_NAME.
```

While, when I read the metadata of BQ `bigquery.datasets().get(...).execute()`

I get the following - meaning, even owner permissions are not sufficient.

```
{
    "kind": "bigquery#dataset",
    "datasetReference": {
        "projectId": "PROJECT_ID",
        "datasetId": "DATASET_ID"
    },
    "creationTime": "...",
    "access": [
        {
            "specialGroup": "projectWriters",
            "role": "WRITER"
        },
        {
            "role": "WRITER",
            "userByEmail": "service_account@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
        },
        {
            "specialGroup": "projectOwners",
            "role": "OWNER"
        },
        {
            "role": "OWNER",
            "userByEmail": "service_account@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
        },
        {
            "specialGroup": "projectReaders",
            "role": "READER"
        }
    ],
    "etag": "...",
    "lastModifiedTime": "1488658209437",
    "id": "PROJECT_ID:DATASET_ID",
    "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/PROJECT_ID/datasets/DATASET_ID"
}
```

Comment: check if there is no typo in the long service account email address, try to recreate maybe a temporary glitch is behind

Comment: What IAM roles do you have assigned to the service account when you look at the console?

Comment: @GrahamPolley apparently, the `gcloud auth activate-service-account` was changed recently, and now needed account provided in position 0 in addition to `--key-file` - guess that's why it did not work